# Autotest and Title test failing in chapter 3 of Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial by Michael Hartl - Perhaps Gem version miss match

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial by Michael Hartl. I have a hard time getting past the testing error. I can test the existence of pages fine but as soon as I want to test the title it fails. I'm sure I followed the text to the T

My auto test also fails because of some gem version miss-match I tried everything I could find online but nothing helped.

Can someone also pint me to the right place for rspec function documentation?

I appreciate any help. Thanks

This is the link to my public repository https://justfarnaz@github.com/justfarnaz/Sample_app_new.git

I'm running Rails 3.1.1 and the Gemfile bellow.

Both error messages and the Gemfile are bellow.

**// Failing message after I run bundle exec rspec spec/**

.F...

Failures:

1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home ")
       expected following output to contain a Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home  tag:
       
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12

Finished in 0.05239 seconds
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:10 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

**Autotest error**

autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/justfarnaz/Documents/Ruby/sites/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.7.1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.6.4. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in`setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in`gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/justfarnaz/Documents/Ruby/sites/sample_app/config/boot.rb:6
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/justfarnaz/Documents/Ruby/sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/justfarnaz/Documents/Ruby/sites/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/justfarnaz/Documents/Ruby/sites/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:50
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/justfarnaz/Documents/Ruby/sites/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in`load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in`map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in`run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in`run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/bin/rspec:4

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'


group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
    gem 'webrat' , '0.7.1' 
    gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. Try to edit Gemfile and change version of

> gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'

in test and development groups to 2.7.0